# ASP.net core gRPC Service in docker replies with wrong ssl certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, certificate, grpc

I created a gRPC WebService (netcoreapp3.1) that is hosted in a docker container with C#. It runs well locally. 
I do a docker build with following dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
# USER ContainerAdministrator
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443

WORKDIR /app
COPY publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
```

On an Ubuntu 20.4 machine I start the container by

```
docker run --rm -it -p 32555:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=secretpassword -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/ourdomain.de.pfx  -v /home/user/.aspnet/https:/https/ myservice
```

That produces the following output

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://[::]:443
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

The ourdomain.de.pfx was created by my admin for our domain.
If I call the service from a client I get an execption

> Error on call 'CreateGaebAsync' with SSL certificate check:
>   Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Error starting gRPC call.
>   HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see
>   inner exception. AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is
>   invalid according to the validation procedure.")

To get more infos I added a HttpClientHandler to the GrpcChannel

```
    private GrpcChannel CreateGrpcChannelWithDangerousIgnoreSslCertificate()
            {
                var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                httpHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = DangerousServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback;
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
                return GrpcChannel.ForAddress(serviceUri, new GrpcChannelOptions() { HttpClient = httpClient });
            }
    private bool DangerousServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback(HttpRequestMessage arg1, X509Certificate2 arg2, X509Chain arg3, SslPolicyErrors arg4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg1);
            Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate2:");
            Console.WriteLine(arg2);
            Console.WriteLine("X509Chain:");
            Console.WriteLine(arg3);
            Console.WriteLine("SslPolicyErrors:");
            Console.WriteLine(arg4);
            // No check of Certificate is done so this will accept any response.
            // For production this has to be fixed by acceptiong only valid SSL certificates!!!
            return true;
        }
```

The validation callback generates the following output

```
Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://computername.ourdomain.de:32555/mysvc.TextService/CreateText',
    Version: 2.0, Content: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.PushUnaryContent`2[MyService.CreateTextRequest,MyService.CraeteTextReply],
 Headers: 
 { 
   User-Agent:    grpc-dotnet/2.29.0.0 
   TE: trailers 
   grpc-accept-encoding: identity,gzip 
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
   Content-Type: application/grpc 
 } 
 X509Certificate2:
 [Subject] 
   CN=localhost 
 [Issuer] 
   CN=localhost 
 [Serial Number]
   00F059E1CA7B219BF3 
 [Not Before]
   09.06.2020 07:29:50 
 [Not After]
   09.06.2021 07:29:50 
 [Thumbprint]
   E272ACFB1C55B28A6ED08A0AFD2F7D97801447AF 
X509Chain: 
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain 
SslPolicyErrors: 
RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
```

I expected to see the certificate infos from ourdomain.de.pfx but what I get seems to imply that the certificate given at ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/ourdomain.de.pfx is ignored?!
I have nearly no experience with certificates at all...
If I start the container with a wrong password or a wrong name for the pfx, I get appropriate error messages. So it seems to me the webservice should use the right one.
Because I am not sure if I have to set the port within the container (443) or the mapped port of host machine (32555), I changed

```
 ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
```

by

```
ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=32555
```

when running the docker container with no success.
Could you explain, what I'm missing, please?

Answer (score 1):

Trust nobody but yourself.

I regenerated the pfx on the ubuntu host from the original files and the SSL connection is working as expected.

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey certificate.key -in certificate.crt
```

Comment: The ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT had to be 32555 in my example. That is the port on the host which is redirected to the container port 443.